# Getting Transaction was rolled back in a different thread exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, wildfly-10

So I have 2 xa-datsources configured in my Wildfly 10 Application Server and I am using Hibernate ORM 5.2.9. And the DB is Postgres 9.6

In my application I have an EJB which has 2 nested for loops and I have to read data from a table in every iteration of the nested loop. But after some time I'm getting this exception

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!

I can't understand why this is happening. I have a small proof of concept application which uses JDBC to connect to the DB and everything works fine.

**EDIT**
This is the stacktrace after the exception I mentioned is thrown:

> 12:39:07,319 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-7)
>   ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action
>   0:ffffac280184:2edc54df:598adfb2:27f
>       12:39:07,320 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-7) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component
>   ejb/calculationResource for method public void
>   com.actuariado.smartsolve.services.api.calculation.CalculationResource.calculateFinancial(org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput)
>   throws com.actuariado.smartsolve.exceptions.AppException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:137)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:279)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>               at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>               at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
>               at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>               at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>               at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>               at com.actuariado.smartsolve.services.api.calculation.CalculationResource$$$view200.calculateFinancial(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>               at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>               at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>               at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>               at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>               at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>               at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>               at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>               at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>               at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>               at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>               at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>               at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffffac280184:2edc54df:598adfb2:27f status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >'
>   was already rolled back
>               at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:98)
>               ... 88 more

Comment: Do you have more info on this? Are you absolutely sure that your transaction isn't actually rolled back?

Comment: M. Prokhorov - I have edited the question to include the stacktrace. Hope it helps in giving you more info. Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible that you did a remote call to and ejb in this container inside this transaction?

Comment: I don't think so. All my EJB's are local

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I think I figured out what's happening.
As it seems, when my EJB method is invoked the Container creates a global JTA transaction, or something like that, which has a timeout of 5 minutes (default from Wildfly).
Since my business logic (the nested loops) is taking more than that time to process, the transaction times out and throws that exception when I try to access the DB again.

Comment: How did you fix the problem?

Comment: @IvandroJao did YOU fix the problem though?

Comment: That's right. I got the same problem and the solution was to increase the transaction Wildfly timeout. To do so, edit the standalone.xml file and add a timeout property inside the transaction subsystem object:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:4.0">

Just add the line:

<coordinator-environment default-timeout="6000"/>

Where 6000 is the max seconds quantity to wait for a Transaction Response.